# Plot legend with two character pch symbols

Tags: r, legend

I have a map of shapes that are labelled with numbers 1:200. I want to create a legend that decodes these numbers. So I tried (keeping it to 20 for easy reading).

```
plot(c(1,20), c(0,3), type="n")
xx <- c(0,1,1,0)
thelabels <- paste(LETTERS[1:20], LETTERS[1:20], sep="")
for (i in 1:20){
  polygon(xx, c(0,0,1,1))
  text(mean(xx), 0.5, i)
  xx <- xx + 1
}
legend("topleft", "groups", 
  legend = thelabels, pch=as.character(c(1:20)),
  ncol=4
)
```

[image: Attempted legend with numbers]

However, this doesn't work because `pch` only admits 1-length strings. How can I create a legend where the key is based on the numbers 1:200 not just the first digit of each? or do something equivalent to forcing `pch` into accepting multilength strings?  (Note that `thelabels` contains longer text so I can't directly label the shapes with `thelabels`.)

Comment: Do you think that a legend with 200 labels is still readable?

Comment: Most readers will be interested in only one entry and the numbering of the legend will mean that 200 labels is feasible. Using @gung's method has a readable result.

Comment: But I would be open to another decoding method that may be more readable.

Comment: it depends how your polygon are disposed... Maybe if you give more details of how your polygons are , I can propose something. Then I think also that one of the weakness of basic plots comparing to high levels (ggplot2/lattice) , is the fact that it is entirely the responsibility of the user to ensure
that the legend corresponds to the plot...

Comment: It's a map. Similar to a map of postcodes/zip codes and then a side legend with the name of the locality of the postcode sorted by postcode. Unfortunately, I don't have a good data frame of locations -- I am manually placing the polygons essentially.

Comment: Get a look at [`ggmap` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html). I am pretty sure it would be useful, for example `geocode(zip_code)` will give you the (lat,lon) of the location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a total <strike>kludge</strike> workaround:

```
plot(c(1,20), c(0,3), type="n")
xx <- c(0,1,1,0)
thelabels <- paste(1:20, " ", LETTERS[1:20], LETTERS[1:20], sep="")
for (i in 1:20){
  polygon(xx, c(0,0,1,1))
  text(mean(xx), 0.5, i)
  xx <- xx + 1
}
legend("topleft", "groups", 
       legend = thelabels, pch="",
       ncol=4)
```

Comment: Haha! I didn't want to give the check mark, but I really can't fault this method.

Comment: You can remove the check mark, if you like @Hugh. There may be a 'real' way to do this; I just don't know what it is. I think it's an interesting question, actually.

Comment: May sound silly but I spend hours looking for a solution like that, trying hard to find the right `pch`, knowing that I already use paste and the index to create my label it _never_  occured me to use pch="". Saved my day 9 years later! (and if someone pass around with a better `base r` solution please it will be more than welcome!)